# convert string of ints and floats to a float array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, casting, floating-point

what I'm trying to do is to send a string over the network. the point is that the server which receives the string must make the sum of all the numbers and send it back. so i think the easiest way is to take the string and put it in a float array (it does not matter if ints get in there aswell, since the final sum will be a float number).

unfortunately i have no idea how to do that, or more exactly, how to approach it. how do i take the numbers 1 by 1 from a string (let's say, each number is separated by a space)? there must be some function but i can't find it.

the language is plain C under unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) to convert the first number in the string to `double`. Add that to your sum, then use the `endptr` return value argument to figure out if you need to convert another, and if so from where. Iterate until the entire string has been processed.

The prototype for `strtod()` is:

```
double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
```

Also note that you can run into precision issues when treating integers as floating-point.

Comment: IMO, this is the best proposed solution. The other solutions all use “evil” functions that modify their arguments or maintain internal state.

Comment: this clearly looks like the easiest solution and it's exactly what i wanted. i argued a bit with it because i didn't realize where the endpointer should come from, but alas i made it work. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) to read from a stream, just like you would use scanf to read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` to split your string and `atof` to convert it to float.

```
char* p;
float farr[100];
int i = 0;
//str is your incoming string
p = strtok(str," ");
while (p != NULL)
{
    farr[i] = atof(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

I just ran it in an online compiler - http://ideone.com/b3PNTr

Answer (score -1):

you can use sscanf() to read the formatted input from a string.
    you can use something like

```
string=strtok(input," ")
while(string!=NULL)
{ sscanf(string,"%f",&a[i]);
  i++;
string=strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

inside a loop. you can use even atof() instead of using sscanf() with %f.

Comment: You left out an 's' on `sscanf()` in your example.

Comment: This doesn't say anything about how to skip the beginning of `string` to get to the next number.

Comment: @unwind ya right. now i have specified how to get the string.